# How to make snap Firefox use locally installed fonts?

Tags: firefox, fonts, snap

I need to use an intranet app which relies on locally installed fonts for its look, but snap version of Firefox by default doesn't look into user's ~/.fonts. Is there a workaround for that? If not, are there plans to address this specific use case?

Comment: For an authoritative answer, you would need to ask Mozilla (whom we are not); they make the Firefox snap.

Comment: For the terminal in JupyterLab I was able to put fonts into `.local/share/fonts`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*There is currently a bug that prevents Firefox from correctly using locally installed fonts. See: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1760996*

I have set up a workaround on my computer using **symlinks**:

- `~/snap/firefox/current/.local/share/fonts` → `~/.local/share/fonts`
- `~/snap/firefox/current/.config/fontconfig` → `~/.config/fontconfig`

First you create the symbolic links.

After that, you run

```bash
fc-cache -f -r
```

to force Firefox to use the refreshed font cache.

Finally, restart Firefox to make the change take effect.

---

## Example

I have installed the Apple's SF Pro fonts on my computer. Here is what I got after I have set up these symlinks, opened up https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/, and changed the global font family (as defined in `<html>` of that page) to SF Pro Text:

[image: Fetch Standard (SF Pro Text)]

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there is such a plan. But how about putting the fonts in `/usr/local/share/fonts` instead?